# Get Theme details of SharePoint site using CSOM

Tags: csom, pnp-powershell, pnp-provision

Is there way to get current Theme details of a SharePoint site using CSOM **https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteA**

I read [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-csom) and it doesn't have a method

Comment: Check [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/piyushksingh.com/2014/02/13/get-the-current-theme-properties-of-a-sharepoint-website-using-client-object-model-c/amp/) if it helps. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Ganesh Sanap  It gives '.spcolor' and font but i wonder that why it doesn't give json format like this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-rest-api#applytheme